# What is the maximum number of processes that can be used in android?

Tags: android, process

I am trying to use the `getRunnningTasks(int maxNum)`.

I do not know what value should I set in the number `maxNum`.

So, I am going to set the maximum number of processes to `maxNum`.

What is the maximum number of processes that can be used in android?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: A helpful programmer's proverb I once heard goes, "If you have to ask what the upper limit is, you're probably doing it wrong."

Comment: I want the information of all the processes currently running.
However, getRunnningTasks requires an argument.
Why do we need arguments getRunnningTasks?

If set to a large value as an argument, you do a slow processing speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxNum` sets the maximum number of tasks that `getRunningTasks` will return.  You could just pass in `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if you want to make sure you get all tasks.